# Sending an email via command line--body not included

Tags: email, batch-file

Why isn't the body being ignored?

```
@ECHO OFF    
START mailto:me@me.nl?subject=Technical%%20Issue..?body="lalala"
```

Comment: Using all caps is unacceptable.  Please don't do that again.  Also, being rude to people who try to help you is never acceptable.  Take some time to cool off and think about it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure you can add content to an email that way, but try replacing the second ? with & so that it's at least a correct query string. Also that quotes will probably be an issue. You should URL-encode the body content.

Comment: You are right, but the & has to be escaped. `START mailto:me@me.nl?subject=Technical%%20Issue..^&body="one%%20two"`